# Laravel 5 nested curly braces on dynamic filed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, nested, laravel-blade

I want to create dynamic field on my controller and pass variable to blade.
I have controller like this

```
public function create()
{
   $AdditionalField=AdditionalFieldController::generateHTML(1);
   return view("addcontact")->with(['AdditionalField'=$AdditionalField]);
}
```

output of `print_r($AdditionalField)` is:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-right">
    <label class="text-gray-dark"  for="address_2">address_2</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
     <input class="form-control " id="address_2" value="{{isset($editContact['address_2'])?$editContact['address_2']:''}}"  name="address_2">
</div>
```

and on my blade I use this code for  show fields.

```
 {!!  $AdditionalField !!}
```

Output is

[image: mypic]

but I want to show me this on blade

[image: mypic]

Updated

```
  public static function generateHTML($moduleId)
{       
   $AdditionalFieldKeys = AdditionalFieldKey::where("module_id", $moduleId)->get();
    $html = '';
    foreach ($AdditionalFieldKeys as $additionalFieldKey) {
        $type = AdditionalFieldController::getInputType($additionalFieldKey->additional_field_key_name);
        $fieldName = AdditionalFieldController::getInputName($additionalFieldKey->additional_field_key_name);
        $file = AdditionalFieldController::getTemplate($type);
        $variable = AdditionalFieldController::getVariables($fieldName,$this->model_name);
        $html .= AdditionalFieldController::fillTemplate($variable, $file);
    }
    return $html;
}
    public static function getTemplate($type)
{
    $file = base_path('modules/AdditionalField/view/' . $type . '.stub');
    return file_get_contents($file);
}
```

Comment: tried using `{!! isset( $editContact['address_2'] ) ? $editContact['address_2'] : '' !!}` ?

Comment: Well you have a blade template inside a string, you have to convert that first into html and then pass it to the view, so you basically need two view calls. You might want to have a look at [this StringBladeCompiler thing](https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler).

Comment: @dekts it did not work.....

Comment: can you share you ```generateHTML()``` code? you should return the HTML instead of echoing

Comment: You need exactly what @vstm said. You need to compile the string and pass it to the view, you can't parse blade syntax that's stored in a variable natively.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy How can I do this?

Comment: Share your generateHTML() function code ?

Comment: @DsRaj I add `generateHTML()`

Comment: @jogesh_pi I add `generateHTML()`

Comment: For a while can you change it to: <?php isset($editContact['address_2'])?$editContact['address_2']:''?>

Comment: @DsRaj Did not make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to use something like the [StringBladeCompiler](https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler).

To install this component you have to execute two steps (which are also documented in the readme of StringBladeCompiler):

1. Run `composer require "wpb/string-blade-compiler"` in your project directory
2. In `config/app.php` replace the line `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class` with `Wpb\String_Blade_Compiler\ViewServiceProvider::class`, like that:

   ```
   //Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
   Wpb\String_Blade_Compiler\ViewServiceProvider::class,
   ```

After that, you can use string based templates. So in your controller you have to use two `view` calls. In the end it would look like that:

```
public function create()
{
    $AdditionalField=AdditionalFieldController::generateHTML(1);
    $editContact['address_2']='ali';

    return view("addcontact")->with([
        'AdditionalField'=>view(['template' => $AdditionalField])->with(['editContact' => $editContact])
    ]);
}
```

If you have to supply any variables to the "inner" view you can add a `with` just like with the outer view call.

The other solution would be to just refactor your approach and not generate a string-template but use stuff like "includes".

Comment: It is not work correctly. When I use this `@php $editContact['address_2']='test'; @endphp
     {!!  $AdditionalField !!}` on blade, dose not show me `test` on my text html element

Comment: Well yes of course because at this stage `$AdditionalField` contains the fully rendered HTML as string, and as you know blade does not "recursively" render the templates . You have to set the "$editContact" in your controller in the "inner" view using `with`.

Comment: I use this but dose not work correctly.  `$editContact['address_2']='test'; return view("addcontact")->with(['AdditionalField'=>view(['template' => $AdditionalField]),'editContact'=>$editContact])`

Comment: and when I use  this on blade `{{print_r($editContact)}}` show me `Array ( [address_2] => test ) `

Comment: I have updated my code, this should work. But it seems like you don't understand that there are now two separate `view` renderings going on. So each `view` has it's own scope and unless you inject the values in both `with` calls.